# Append "i" tag plus text to span

Tags: javascript, angularjs, append

I have this angular script to build out a div. the problem i'm having is that it appends the .text inside the i tag and not as a sibling of i.

Hope this makes sense.

```
            var body = placeWrapper
                .append('div')
                .attr('class', 'thm-listing__body');

                body.append('span')
                .attr('class', 'thm-listing__location')
                .append('i')
                .attr('class', 'fa fa-map-marker')
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.Address;
                });
```

this dive is suppose to render out as follows:

```
<div class="thm-listing__body">
<span class="thm-listing__location">
<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
The text here
</span>
</div>
```

But it currently renders out:

```
<div class="thm-listing__body">
<span class="thm-listing__location">
<i class="fa fa-map-marker">The text here</i>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not the *Angular way*...

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `text` to `i` tag and you want a text for span right so set text just after append span instead of after append `i` as below

```
    var body = placeWrapper
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'thm-listing__body');

        body.append('span')
        .attr('class', 'thm-listing__location')
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.Address;
        })
        .append('i')
        .attr('class', 'fa fa-map-marker');
```

**Update**

Set icon before span text use [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) as per below

```
var body = placeWrapper
            .append('div')
            .attr('class', 'thm-listing__body');

            body.append('span')
            .attr('class', 'thm-listing__location')
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.Address;
            })
            .prepend('i')
            .attr('class', 'fa fa-map-marker');
```

Comment: It needs to be before the text, i did try it like that but then the icon sits at the end of the text and not at the beginning.

Comment: Please find my updated answer use `prepend()` for this

Comment: no it does not seem to work :  body.append(...).attr(...).text(...).prepend is not a function is the error i get when using  prepend as above

Comment: can you please make a fiddle so i can figure out what exactly going wrong?